# Trying to erase corresponding cell content based on value change of another cell on the same row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the first time I am trying to create the equivalent of a macro in GSheet with Javascript (I am used to VBA macros in Excel).

I thought this short JS script would work once tied to the onChange event of my GSheet:

// When a cell in column BD (56) is changed to value 0 then, if the corresponding cell on the same row in column AR (44) has value 'Approved', clear the 'Approved' string.

```
function onChange(e) {
if(e.range.columnStart === 56) { 
    if(e.value=='0' && e.range.offset(0,-12).value=='Approved'){
      e.range.offset(0,-12).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

BTW I do not get any errors. When I manually change the value to 0 in BD the Approved contentn in AR stays. I wish I knew how to debug this.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: 1) Is the value of the cell going to change via formula/script or by user input? 2) if you want to trigger an event when the value of the cell changes you want to replace `onChange` with `onEdit`. To summarize, `onEdit` is triggered when the **user** changes the value of the cell. If this is what you want, then use that. Both `onChange` and `onEdit` **won't work** if the operation is done by a script or formula, so be careful with this.

Comment: The value will change by formulas (not by user). This is why I used onChange. Now I also added to same code to a onEdit so I can set manually a BD cell to 0 and see if the AR Approved value gets removed. But it does not :-(

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. You can't trigger a function when a formula changes the value of the cell. Regarding the manual on edit  input that does not work please Google: how to debug an onEdit trigger and open the first stackoverflow link that pops up.

Comment: Anyway, the obvious workaround is to put a simple formula in column AR to do the job. Namely, an if condition to check the value of column BD and return empty if BD is 0. That's way faster but also your only option.

Comment: Will it be possible if you could share a sample sheet? I understood your goal , I just want to verify the issues that you've encountered and to be able to provide possible solutions. Or you can use the suggested workaround provided by @soMario. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: This is the event object for onChange event:`{"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"EDIT","source":{},"triggerUid":"id","user":{"email":"email","nickname":"name"}}`  notice no range property no columnStart property  no value property.

Comment: This is the event object for onEdit event: `{"authMode":"FULL","range":{"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":3,"rowEnd":4,"rowStart":4},"source":{},"triggerUid":"id","user":{"email":"email","nickname":"name"},"value":"value}`

Comment: soMario I cannot use a formula since the content 'Approved' is manually selected by my users. I am looking for a way to erase that value when the corresponding BD cell is at 0.

Comment: MetaMan the onEdit event should have at least worked whne I manually set the BD value to 0. It does not.

Comment: @soMario  thanks for your feedbacks. I replied in the above comment.

Comment: @MetaMan  thanks for your feedbacks. I replied in the above comment.

Comment: @Ron M my company prevents sharing docs outside the company Gooble business account. Sorry. It is easy to test however, 1 column with a Approved string and the next one with a 1 or 0 value.

Comment: The onEdit even may have but your function is onChange(e) not onEdit(e)

Comment: And you onChange is definitely not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your onEdit() is not working is because there is no `value` parameter in Range object. When you use [Range.offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset), It will return a [Range object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), to get the value of the cell you need to use [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

### Sample Working Code (With debug logs):

```
function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log(e.range.columnStart);
  Logger.log(e.value);
  Logger.log(e.range.offset(0,-12).value);
  Logger.log(e.range.offset(0,-12).getColumn());
  if(e.range.columnStart === 56) { 
    if(e.value=='0' && e.range.offset(0,-12).getValue()=='Approved'){
      e.range.offset(0,-12).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

### Execution Log:

[image]

- Notice that when you try to get the value of column AR using `e.range.offset(0,-12).value`, the value is `null`
- Replace that with `e.range.offset(0,-12).getValue()` to get the cell's value

### Note:

You can debug your trigger by adding logs then check the execution tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ron M ! Very helpful. So I guess there is not way to run a script to be triggered by an automatic value change (e.g., from a formula) in gsheet. Too bad :-(

Comment: Glad to help. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)